# Использование кеша и куков из обычного режима браузера в приватном режиме

Tags: cookie, internet-explorer, кэширование

Всем привет!

Вопрос: есть Интернет Эксплорер версии 11+.
Допустим я зашёл на сайт *mysite.com*, авторизоваться там, нажал сохранить логин-пароль. Закрыл браузер. Открыл новое окно Интернет Эксплорера в приватном режиме и перешёл по адресу *mysite.com*.

Будет ли браузер в приватном режиме использовать хоть какие-то куки и кеш из предыдущей сессии обычного режима браузера?

Comment: Нет конечно. В этом же и смысл приватного режима

Comment: Хотя про кеш не уверен, но куки точно будут новые

Comment: Интересует использование и того, и того, абсолютно новая сессия или часть старой все таки будет?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4026200/windows-browse-inprivate-in-microsoft-edge ничего не используется

Comment: Там же вроде указано что не сохраняется, а не не используется?

Comment: Ну это же несложно проверить